# Class not found in JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, sar

I have a jboss service. I try to load a class from different jar file, it always gives in BEA jdk1.5. It works fine sun jdk1.6. Any clue? I have a archive in abcd.sar which calls a Schedulable class from xyz.jar. So far fine. When I try instantiate a class (by `new` or reflection) from another jar file I get ClassNotFoundException. The jar files are in the lib folder.

Comment: How are you oading the class ? Any code ? What error are you getting ? stack trace ?

Comment: Which class?  This is a confusing question.  Did it once work in BEA and doesn't now with JBOSS?  Are you trying to port it from one to the other?  Did you change from JDK 6 to JDK 5?  Is it a class that's new to JDK 6?  If yes, that would explain it.  You'll get better results if you edit your question.

Answer (score 3):

There was an issue in early 5.0 https://jira.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-5900 which did not occur in version 4.x

I usually use the web console to check how hard jboss was trying to find fhe class. In some cases I had to define a loader repository (applies to ear).

In other cases I put the shared jar in jboss_home/server/default/lib.